# Deleting table view cell without a red default delete button at left side

Tags: ios, uitableview

how to delete cell of table view without  a  red default  delete button  at left side (peforming delete action on anoher button) so can any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[listTableView beginUpdates];
[listTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber inSection:0]]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft]; // there are a few other animations, check out the enum
// Remove the cell's contents from your data source, for example:
// [contentsArray removeObjectAtIndex:rowNumber];
[listTableView endUpdates];
```